# What is the meaning of "gas" as opposed to "transaction cost" and "execution cost" when Remix reports overall gas expense?

Tags: remix

Hi: When I Deploy or execute a function I get three categories of cost:

- gas
- transaction cost
- execution cost

For example:

```
gas:    32296 gas
transaction cost:   28083 gas 
execution cost: 28083 gas
```

I understand what transaction and execution costs are, but don't know what the first `gas` value means or how it is calculated.

Help?

I am attaching a screenshot that illustrates what I mean.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**gas** : Total gas supplied for the transaction, the allowed "gas limit" which the transaction can use for its execution.

**transaction cost**: Total gas consumed for the transaction, can be anything upto the amount of the gas supplied for the transaction (until it hits `blockGasLimit`).

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Tell me please, is there anyway to figure out how the allowed "gas limit" has been calculated? In the example above, I did not provide the number 32296 anywhere. Thus, I am curious about how that gas number was determined.

Comment: The answer ignored the 3rd cost: execution cost